# How to execute methods from a JS class at the same time using an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a submit button and I want to click it and run first `calcArea` method, and then `printArea` but all this just by pressing one time the submit button, so that my console prints:

```
100
```

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="nameForm" onclick="square.calcArea()" onclick="square.printArea()">
        <input type="submit" value="print area in console" id="btn">
    </form>

    <script>
        class Rectangle {
            constructor(height, width) {
                this.height = height;
                this.width = width;
            }

            printArea() {
                console.log(this.calcArea());
            }

            calcArea() {
                return this.height * this.width;
            }
        }
        const square = new Rectangle(10, 10);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I tried to do this in the form using two times `onclick()`, but it doesn´t work because It doesn´t show anything in console.

I hope someone can help, thank you.

Comment: `printArea` is already calling `calcArea`, so just call `printArea` in your `onclick`. You also need to make square a `var`, because `const` is block-scoped. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<button onclick="rectangle('PRINT_AREA')">Print Area</button>

<script>
    class Rectangle {
        constructor(height, width) {
            this.height = height;
            this.width = width;
        }

        printArea() {
            console.log(this.calcArea());
        }

        calcArea() {
            return this.height * this.width;
        }
    }
    const square = new Rectangle(10, 10);
    function rectangle(type) {
        switch(type) {
        case "PRINT_AREA":
            square.printArea()
        default:
            console.log("error")
      }
    }
</script>
```